# Creating a customBaseController for an ASP.Net MVC site?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

With the project that I am working on I am finding that at the beginning and end of each action I have the same code to retrieve and then store an object in TempData[]. The code is consistent between all actions so I was wondering if it would be reasonable to create a base controller class to do that redundant reconstitution and storing of the object in TempData[]?

Is there a smarter way?

My current code:

```
public ActionResult Index(StepOne data)
{
    var customer = TempData["customer"] as Customer;

    //do stuff with customer

    TempData["customer"] =customer;

    return View();
}
```

Comment: Have a look at Action filters; they contain logic that is executed before and after a controller action executes.

Comment: Don't use a base controller, it's just more headache than it's worth.  Definitely use and ActionFilter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you create a controller with the name of BaseController or some other controller and then inherit your other controllers from this BaseController just like in the code written below.

```
//Your base controller
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    //This will be executed after every action call on the controllers inherited from this BaseController.
    //You can use OnActionExecuting in case you want the execution before the actions execution in your other controllers.
    protected override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        Controller controller = filterContext.Controller as Controller;
        if (controller != null)
        {
            var customer = controller.TempData["customer"] as Customer;

            //do stuff with customer

            controller.TempData["customer"] = customer;
        }
    }
}

//Then your other controller
public class HomeController : BaseController
{
    public ActionResult Index(StepOne data)
    {
        //You can get your TempData here too.
        var customer = TempData["customer"] as Customer;
        return View();
    }
}
```

Please let me know if it doesn't work or you need to alter this code to some other kind of behavior.